# How can i set form and iframe tag between header and footer, css?

Tags: html, css, forms, iframe, footer

I have no idea why that happens! I didn't set any z-index for my elements, but footer is obviously on the top of form and iframe. I don't understand why...

```
<div class="frontpage1">
  <div class="frontpage1-text">

       .............

       <iframe id="map" src="" width="600" height="460" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen >
            </iframe>

    <footer id="tail">
    <br><br>
      <img src="../work-files/logo.png" style="width: 160px;" >
      <br>
      <p>RH Stuido Photography | Timless Photography</p>
      <p>rick@rhstudiophoto.com | Abbotsford, British Columbia</p>
     <br><br>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJrWu.png)

and Thats my css code :

```
.container {
    border-radius:5px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:250px;
    width:30%;
}
iframe {
    float:right;    
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:35px;
    right:200px;
}
footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Comment: First Enter this link : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --

Comment: If this post is any indication of how well you notice things...say like what you cut and paste....I suggest that you go back to that source and copy it with a little more care. The code you posted is sloppy and incomplete.

Comment: Your problem is probably with `position: absolute` in iframe. Try change it to relative or remove it.